# opening intent with button click in android

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent

I have a `Button` that when clicked I want to load another `Activity class`. I am unsure where my error is, the code below is what I currently have.

```
skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent skip = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(skip);

}
```

I want to click the skip `Button` and have it load my `MainActivity class`. it gives an error saying to remove arguments to match `Intent()` and when I do that it deletes the `MainActivity.class` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue seems to be of incorrect `Context`. Try using `YouCurrentActivityName.this` instead of just `this` while starting another activity. Something like:

```
Intent skip = new Intent(YourCurrentActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give complete package path in 1st parameter of intent

```
Intent skip = new Intent(Package.YourCurrentActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Check you have added intent-filter in your manifest file
code to add in your manifest file of current activity

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank guys for your comments, I was missing the YourCurrentActivityName.this in my intent declaration